# r(e) Model of a Transistor

Tags: transistors, amplifier

While studying the re model of a common emitter transistor i found these two different models that are considered equivalent. But i do not understand how they can be equivalent when in one figure current source is connected directly to ground and all the current from the source goes to R(L)//R(C) while in other figure current from current source is divided through a node[image]

and only a portion of the current from the current source goes to R(L)//RC.

Comment: *...current from current source is divided through a node* But is that so ? In both cases the current through Rc//Rl is Ic. As Ic is a **current source** it is possible that I b does not go to Rc//Rl but that Ic = Ib + Ie is valid. You should write down the complete expression for these circuits, only then can you prove that they're identical or not.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie here is the link http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/Transistor_theory/?p=9

Comment: Not sure why you want me to look at that explanation, I already know that. What you need to do is fill in the values and relations between Ic, Ie, Ib and Beta and then you'll see that the circuits are equivalent. The source is a controlled source so you cannot just assume that you can "see" how the currents flow from the schematic. You must consider the dependencies also and these are only in the formulas.

Comment: These circuits are equivalent only when you "move" the re resistor into the base terminal. Ie = Ib + Ic = Ib + β*Ib = (β +1)*Ib  So, if you "look" from the base terminal into the BJT you will see (β +1)re "trans-resistance".

Comment: ....and that is the reason I do not like this model at all. For my opinion, it is really misleading - in particular for a beginner. One reason: Some people think that re is a resistive element, which is not true!! It is the inverse transconductance re=1/gm.

Comment: ...more than that - from the first circuit one could derive that the input resistance at the base node (into the transistor) would be re´. And that is wrong! Only the second diagram shows the correct expression.

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to transistor equations and approximations of such for the small-signal model, and thus you can find both models which are equally valid because they are described by these approximations.
In order to understand how both models are valid, let us go a bit deeper into the equations. So we know that:
\begin{equation}
 I_c=I_S\,e^\left(v_{BE}/V_T\right) \quad (1)
\end{equation}
thus if we apply a small signal \$vbe(t)\$ into the base, we end up with \begin{equation} v_{BE}(t)= V_{BE}+v_{be}(t)\quad (2)\end{equation}

(2) into (1) yields:
\begin{equation}
i_C = I_S\,e^\left(\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T} + \frac{v_{be}}{V_T}\right) = I_S\,e^\left(V_{BE}/V_T\right)\,e^\left(v_{be}/V_T\right) = I_C\, e^\left(v_{be}/V_T\right)\quad (3)
\end{equation}

From (3), if we assume \$v_{be}\ll V_T\$ we may approximate (3)

\begin{equation}
i_C\approx I_C\left(1+\frac{v_{be}}{V_T}\right)\quad (4)
\end{equation}

which is an expansion using power series and we have retained only the first two terms and therefore it's called the small-signal approximation.

Then, (4) can be rewritten as

\begin{equation}
i_C= I_C + \frac{I_C}{V_T}\,v_{be}\quad (5)
\end{equation}

and with the result of (5), we finally find the transconductance \$g_m = \frac{I_C}{V_T}\$ which composes the signal component \$i_c=g_m\,v_{be}\$.

From now on, only small signal components are going to be shown. So, for the input resistance seen between base and emitter (addressed as \$r_{\pi}\$), we may write:

\begin{equation}
r_{\pi} = \dfrac{v_{be}}{i_b}\quad (6)
\end{equation}

but \$i_b=\dfrac{i_c}{\beta} = \dfrac{g_m\,v_{be}}{\beta}\$ into (6) yields:

\begin{equation}
r_{\pi}=\dfrac{\beta}{g_m}\quad (7)
\end{equation}

In the same train of thought we can find the emitter resistance (\$r_e\$, which I'll show a bit faster and less talkative):

\begin{equation}
i_e=\dfrac{i_c}{\alpha} = \frac{I_C\,v_{be}}{V_T\,\alpha} = \frac{I_E}{V_T}\,v_{be}\quad (8)
\end{equation}

thus as \$r_e\$ is the base-emitter resistance looking into the emitter, (8) yields:

\begin{equation}
r_e=\frac{v_{be}}{i_e} = \frac{V_T}{I_E}\quad (9)
\end{equation}

Also, as the base-emitter can be considered for both resistances (\$r_e\$ and \$r_{\pi}\$):

\begin{equation}
v_{be}=r_{\pi}\,i_b=r_e\,i_e \implies r_{\pi} = (\beta + 1)\,r_e\quad (10)
\end{equation}

Finally, with the needed gear of components we can jump into the models (\$\pi\$ and T) to understand how they are described by all those equations aforementioned:
\begin{align}
\large\pi-Model
\end{align}

It's pretty straightforward:

the emitter current is given by: \$i_e=i_c+i_b=g_m\,v_{be}+\dfrac{v_{be}}{r_{\pi}}\$.

If we would draw the schematic for the \$\pi\$ model using such equations, the outcome is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzBLYp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and that complies with the sum of currents described above.

\begin{align}
T-Model
\end{align}
Finally, in order to see the equivalence between both \$\pi\$ and T- model, we write the very same equations but seen from a different perspective:

\$i_e=\dfrac{v_{be}}{r_e} = i_b + g_m\,v_{be}\$

It's right off the bat. We have just changed the point of view using the very same equations, which lead us to the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feLRHh.png)</sup>

As you can see, both models have been derived using the same equations, which means both of them are equally valid in the small-signal model regardless of any additional components you insert in your circuit. The point is to understand which can be the advantages of using one over the other. For instance, if you had to take into account the Early effect, that would generate an output resistance (\$r_o\approx\dfrac{V_A}{I_C}\$) between collector and emitter, which would make the math a bit more cumbersome to work with the T-model. Meanwhile, if there were an additional emitter resistance, say \$R_E\$, you would rather use the T-model instead, since it makes math easier than the pi-model approach.

Answer (score 0):

The transistor is simplified, and we get \$R_e I_e \$, with dependent source at collector as Ic=βIb. Now, these two are separated as the the voltage drop across \$R_e \$ is \$R_e I_e \$ and \$ I_e=I_c+I_b => \beta I_b+I_b => (\beta+1)I_b\$ .
put value of \$I_e \$ in \$R_e I_e \$, the drop becomes \$(β+1)R_e I_e \$. Now, \$(β+1)R_e\$ is your resistance and \$ I_b \$ is current flowing through it and hence both are separated. Also, as (β+1)≈β the resistor leg is \$ \beta R_e\$ .

Comment: Please note that the quantity you have named "RE" is dynamic/differential quantity and, hence, must NOT be written with a capital letter. Otherwise, one could think that it is a resistor which is NOT TRUE. It is the inverse of the transconductance gm=1/re. Thus, it is something like a "transresistance" .

Answer (score 0):

These two figures are only EQUIVALENT to determine the value of VOUT.
The figures demand that the reader already has some familiarity; that's a big expectation.

You have to know that VOUT is measured    "at the top of    Rc || RL".
The Rc is the resistor from the COLLECTOR to the +Vcc.   (Vcc is not shown)
The RL is the resistor from the COLLECTOR to GROUND (RL and bypass CAPACITOR, are not shown).
The direction of the COLLECTOR current matches the CURRENT SOURCE  as shown. 
-Vout =  Icollector (as shown)  x  Parallel Rc RL.
The top figure shows Icollector   but does not label the current source as  Ic.
Figure relies on the reader to see and to know that   Ib + Ic = Ie(emitter).
The bottom figure shows : -Vout =  Icollector (as shown)  x  Parallel Rc RL.
The sign of VOUT is (MINUS)   because it is based on applying an input signal, and the TRANSISTOR AMPLIFIER output is an "amplified,  inverted, copy of the input,  (AND the    definition of inverted = (times -1)).